# In C# making a chat program how would you create an ftp feature

Tags: ftp, chat, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have created a chat program and a created GUI for my FTP.I have coded what I think would work for the FTP, but when I run the solution it keeps giving me different results. That is, it creates the file with a different memory set each time.   Here is the relevant coding, the problem appears to happen when it is transfered back to the client:

in server :

```
    //Listens for new commands coming in from the client associated with the client object
    public void Command_Listener()
    {
        foreach (Client C in UI[0].clients)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("2: User: " + username + " has connected...");
            sw.Flush();
            //Notifies other client objects inside the user interface that this one is operational
        }
        while (UI[0].busy)
        { } //waits for the log to not be busy with another task then declares this task is over
        UI[0].busy = true;
        UI[0].Log_Event(username + " has connected..." + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        UI[0].Log_Event("Client username : " + Client_Info[0]);
        UI[0].Log_Event("Client computer name : " + Client_Info[1]);
        UI[0].Log_Event("Client operating system : " + Client_Info[2]);
        UI[0].Log_Event("Client lan IP address : " + Client_Info[3]);
        UI[0].Log_Event("Client wan IP address : " + Client_Info[4]);
        //sends the client info from the client to the server's user interface and the log
        UI[0].busy = false;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                string command = sr.ReadLine();
                //waits for a new message
                if (command[0] == '1')
                    Update_Chat_List(command.Replace("1: ", ""));
                    //Determines the Username has changed and needs to update the list
                if (command[0] == '2')
                    Update_Message_Board(command.Replace("2: ", ""));
                    //Determines the message board on each clients needs to update with the new command included
                if (command == "3: typing" && !typing) //Determines the client's typing
                {
                    typing = true;
                    Update_Chat_List(username);
                }
                if (command == "3: empty" && typing) //Determine the client's not typing
                {
                    typing = false;
                    Update_Chat_List(username);
                }
                if (command[0] == '5') //Determines that a new FTP is in progress
                    Update_FTP_Status(command.Replace("5: ", ""));
                if (command[0] == '6')
                {
                    //Adds the incoming kilobyte of the file to a string list
                    kilos.Add(command.Replace("<heartbeat>", ""));
                }
                if (command[0] == '7')
                {
                    //Tells the server that all pieces of the file have been recieved
                    kilos.Add(command);
                    new Thread(Send_File).Start();
                }
            }
            catch //catchs all listening problems and tells the server the client must be removed and then does a user list update and logs the exit
            {
                sw.Dispose();
                sr.Dispose();
                UI[0].clients.RemoveAt(Client_Index);
                UI[0].Update_Index();
                while (UI[0].busy)
                { }
                UI[0].busy = true;
                UI[0].Log_Event(username + " has disconnected...");
                UI[0].busy = false;
                foreach (Client C in UI[0].clients)
                {
                    C.sw.WriteLine("2: " + username + " has disconnected...");
                    C.sw.Flush();
                }
                Update_Chat_List("");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Send_File() 
    {
        string last = "";
        foreach (string kilo in kilos)
        {
            FTP_Connection[0].sw.WriteLine(kilo);
            FTP_Connection[0].sw.Flush();
            //sends all part of the file and the closing compile command for the client
        }
        ftping = false;
        int length = last.Length;
        FTP_Connection[0].ftping = false;
        //changes ftp status to off
    }

    public void Update_FTP_Status(string user)
    {
        string filename = "";
        bool building = false;
        foreach (char c in user)
        {
            if (building)
                filename = filename + c;
            else if (c == ':')
                building = true;
        }
        //retrieves the filename
        user_to_send_to = user.Replace(":" + filename, "");
        //replaces the filename out of the message to get the user to send to
        foreach (Client User in UI[0].clients)
        {
            if (User.username == user_to_send_to)
            {
                User.sw.WriteLine("5: " + username);
                User.sw.Flush();
                User.sw.WriteLine(filename);
                User.sw.Flush();
                FTP_Connection.Add(User);
                //notifies the client they are recieving a file then setups a direct access to the client the ftp is going to.
            }
        }
    }
```

in client :

```
    //Listens for new commands given by the server
    void Command_Listener()
    {
        Connected = true;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                string Comunicae = sr.ReadLine();
                //recieves the message
                if (Comunicae[0] == '1')
                    User_List_Update(Comunicae.Replace("1: ", ""));
                    //Determines the user list has to be updated
                if (Comunicae[0] == '2')
                    New_Message(Comunicae.Replace("2: ", ""));
                    //Determines the messages board has to be updated
                if (Comunicae[0] == '4')
                    New_Server_Command(Comunicae.Replace("4: ", ""));
                if (Comunicae[0] == '5') //notifies the user theres a new ftp incoming
                {
                    ftping = true;
                    string filenam = sr.ReadLine();
                    File_Name = filenam;
                    FTP_Sender = Comunicae.Replace("5: ", "");
                    Recipients_Message = Comunicae.Replace("5: ", "") + " is sending you " + filenam + " file via ftp...\r\nYou will recieve this file in " + settings[0].driver + "program data\\";
                }
                if (Comunicae[0] == '6')
                {
                    int length = Comunicae.Length;
                    lengths.Add(length);
                    string kilo = Comunicae.Replace("6: ", "");
                    kilos.Add(kilo);
                    //gathers the incoming file parts
                }
                if (Comunicae[0] == '7')
                {
                    new Thread(Compile_File).Start();
                    //Pieces together the file
                }
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                //Kills the client if theres a reading error
                Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void Compile_File()
    {
        int length = kilos[kilos.Count - 1].Length;
        List<byte> file = new List<byte>();
        foreach (string kilo in kilos)  //seperates out each byte in each file part  then adds to the byte list
        {
            string byt = "";
            int helper = 0;
            foreach (char C in kilo)
            {
                if (helper == 3)
                {
                    string temp = byt;
                    file.Add(Convert.ToByte(temp));
                    byt = "";
                    helper = 0;
                }
                if (C != '|')
                {
                    byt = byt + C;
                }
                helper++;
            }
        }
        byte[] final = new byte[file.Count - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i != file.Count - 1; i++) //Converts the byte list to an array
        {
            final[i] = file[i];
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(settings[0].driver + "Program Data\\" + File_Name, final);
        //Writes the file
        ftping = false;
    }


    private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Controler[0].ftping) //Detects transfers in progress
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You already have a file transfer in progress...");
            return;
        }
        if (ftping_users.Contains(User_To_Send_To.Text)) //Detects if the user you try to send to already has a file inbound
        {
            MessageBox.Show(User_To_Send_To.Text + " is has a inbound or outbound file already in progress...");
            return;
        }
        Controler[0].Update_FTP_Status(User_To_Send_To.Text, Selected_File);
        //Aprises the server of a new FTP in progress
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(Current_Directory.Text.Replace(fil, ""));
        //Reads the file
        Thread T = new Thread(() => Get_Kilos(file));
        T.Start();
        //Starts segmenting the file bytes and converting them to strings for transfer
        this.Hide(); 
    }

    public void Get_Kilos(byte[] file)
    {
        List<string> kilos = new List<string>();
        string kilobyte = "";
        foreach (byte B in file)
        {
            string byt = (Convert.ToInt32(B)).ToString();
            if (byt.Length == 1)
                byt = "||" + byt;
            if (byt.Length == 2)
                byt = "|" + byt;
            kilobyte = kilobyte + byt;
            //Makes a bytes string length a standard 3 characters
            if (kilobyte.Length == 3072)
            {
                string temp = "6: " + kilobyte;
                kilos.Add(temp);
                kilobyte = "";
                //Adds the part to a list of file parts
            }
        }
        kilos.Add("6: " + kilobyte);
        foreach (string kilo in kilos)
        {
            int length = kilo.Length;
            Controler[0].sw.WriteLine(kilo);
            Controler[0].sw.Flush();
            //Sends the File parts
        }
        Controler[0].sw.WriteLine("7: Complete...");
        Controler[0].sw.Flush();
        //Lets the server know the transfer is complete
        Controler[0].ftping = false;
    }
```

Comment: You've pasted in nearly 250 lines of code with no comments. Do you expect us to debug it for you?

Comment: Please reduce your code to the smallest program that demonstrates the problem. Also, describe what debugging you've performed, and what the expected inputs and outputs are.

Comment: it's not that easy to reduce this program Raymond without geting rid of the key processes the FTP is entangled with that might be causing the problem.

Comment: @user1508786 **Pro-Tip**. Always do the research [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com), *show* the effort you put in, emphasize subset of code that *you* think is problematic, etc before posting a question like the above. As questions like these will get downvoted and closed in no time, we're not remote debuggers nor mind-readers. Welcome to StackOverflow. :)